# IntelliJ IDEA not recognizing custom CSS module class names with unique naming convention

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webpack, css-modules, css-loader

I'm working on a project that uses custom CSS modules with a unique naming convention. I've configured my css-loader to generate class names in a specific way, and it's working correctly when compiling my styles. However, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't seem to recognize these custom class names

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: {
      auto: (resourcePath) => resourcePath.endsWith('.module.sass'),
      exportLocalsConvention: (name) => name.split('-').slice(1).map(
        (part, index) => (index > 0 ? part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1) : part),
      ).join(''),
      localIdentName: '[local]',
    },
  },
}
```

Even though the styles compile correctly, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't provide auto-completion and other features for my custom class names

I am expecting intellij to recognize my custom convention